# Google Cloud sink can't catch BigQuery tables modification logs of other projects in the same organization

Tags: python, logging, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I've created a Cloud Sink (exporting to a pub/sub topic) but it only scans BigQuery tables modification logs of the current project. I believe it is because of Google logging scope by project.

**Filter**

```
protoPayload.serviceName=bigquery.googleapis.com

protoPayload.methodName=("google.cloud.bigquery.v2.TableService.DeleteTable" OR 
    "google.cloud.bigquery.v2.TableService.UpdateTable" OR 
    "google.cloud.bigquery.v2.TableService.PatchTable")

severity < ERROR
```

**Results**

[image]

How to catch the BigQuery logs of other projects from within the same Sink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scenario you described is known as [**Aggregated Sink**](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/aggregated_sinks#command-line):

This page (link above) describes how to create an aggregated sink that can route log entries from all the Google Cloud projects, folders, and billing accounts of a Google Cloud organization. For instance, you might aggregate and route audit log entries from an organization's Cloud projects to a central destination.

`Without the aggregated sink feature, sinks are limited to routing log entries from the exact resource in which the sink was created: a Google Cloud project, organization, folder, or billing account.`

Such link is a guide of how to setup aggregated sinks, please give it a try.